# Is $(e^x-1)^\alpha/x$ convex? (with $0\leq\alpha\leq 1$ and $x>0$)

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

From plotting it and quick checks, I see that the function $f(x)=(e^x-1)^\alpha/x$ where $0\leq\alpha\leq 1$ and $x>0$ looks convex. However I cannot show it formally. I can compute the second derivate but struggle to show that it is positive. Any help?

As detailed by esoteric-elliptic, the second derivative is
$$f''(x) = \frac{(e^x - 1)^{\alpha - 2}(e^{2x} (\alpha^2x^2 - 2 \alpha x + 2) - e^x (\alpha x^2 - 2\alpha x + 4) + 2)}{x^3}.$$
Given that $x>0$, we have directly that $x^3>0$ and $(e^x - 1)^{\alpha - 2}\geq 0$. So we "only need to show" that
$$e^{2x} (\alpha^2x^2 - 2 \alpha x + 2) - e^x (\alpha x^2 - 2\alpha x + 4) + 2 \ge 0.$$
However, I struggle to prove it even though I see that it seems true by plotting it/evaluating numerically.

Comment: The map is $C^2$. Derivatives are our friends.

Comment: Just study the sign of $f''(x).$

Comment: Indeed! Also thought about it, still not sure how I can show that it is positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $k(x)=\alpha(\log (e^x-1)-\log x)-(1-\alpha)\log x,$ enough is to prove that $k$ is convex. Using $\sinh y>y$ for $y>0$ we get
$$k''(x)=\alpha\left(-\frac{1}{(2\sinh (x/2))^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+\frac{1-\alpha}{x^2}\geq 0.$$

Thanks, Martin R!

Comment: This is really nice. I had also shown that $\log f(x)$ is convex, but my proof is more complicated because I did not see the connection to $\sinh$.

Comment: Nice! I did not expect to have new answers after I had found one myself :p anyway, these ones are much more too the point, thanks!

Comment: Btw, a related question, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4767145/963945 maybe you also have some inputs there!

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) := \alpha \ln(\mathrm{e}^x - 1) - \ln x$. Since $f'' = (\mathrm{e}^g)'' = \mathrm{e}^g (g')^2 + \mathrm{e}^g g''$, it suffices to prove that $g''\ge 0$.

We have
$$g'(x) = \frac{a \mathrm{e}^x}{\mathrm{e}^x - 1} - \frac{1}{x} = a + \frac{a}{\mathrm{e}^x - 1} - \frac{1}{x}$$
and
$$g''(x) = - \frac{a\mathrm{e}^x}{(\mathrm{e}^x - 1)^2} + \frac{1}{x^2}
\ge -\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{(\mathrm{e}^x - 1)^2} + \frac{1}{x^2} \ge 0$$
where we use
$$-\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x/2}}{\mathrm{e}^x - 1} + \frac{1}{x} \ge 0.$$
(*Note*: Let $h(x) := \mathrm{e}^x - 1 - x\mathrm{e}^{x/2}$. We have
$h'(x) = \mathrm{e}^x - \mathrm{e}^{x/2} - \frac{x}{2}\mathrm{e}^{x/2}
= \mathrm{e}^{x/2} (\mathrm{e}^{x/2} - 1 - x/2) \ge 0$. Also, $h(0) = 0$.
Thus, $h(x) \ge 0$ on $x > 0$. )

We are done.

Comment: Nice! I did not expect to have new answers after I had found one myself :p anyway, these ones are much more too the point, thanks!

Comment: @Fr2021 Sometimes, $(\mathrm{e}^g)'' = \mathrm{e}^g (g')^2 + \mathrm{e}^g g''$ is helpful.

Comment: Sure, in other words, composition rules that preserve convexity

Comment: Btw, a related question, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4767145/963945 maybe you also have some inputs there!

Comment: @Fr2021 Nice question. (+1)  I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x) = \frac{(e^x-1)^\alpha}{x}$$
If $\alpha = 0$, it is clear that $f$ is convex. Let $0 < \alpha \le 1$. Then,
$$f''(x) = \frac{(e^x - 1)^{\alpha - 2}(e^{2x} (\alpha^2x^2 - 2 \alpha x + 2) - e^x (\alpha x^2 - 2\alpha x + 4) + 2)}{x^3}$$
For $0 < \alpha \le 1$,
$$e^{2x} (\alpha^2x^2 - 2 \alpha x + 2) - e^x (\alpha x^2 - 2\alpha x + 4) + 2 \ge 0$$
for all $x\in \Bbb R$. Furthermore, $e^x - 1$ and $x^3$ are both strictly increasing functions, which change sign at $x = 0$, so that
$$\frac{(e^x-1)^{\alpha - 2}}{x^3} > 0$$
for all $x\in \Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$. Therefore, $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, showing that $f$ is convex.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. How do you show that $$e^{2x} (\alpha^2x^2 - 2 \alpha x + 2) - e^x (\alpha x^2 - 2\alpha x + 4) + 2 \ge 0$$? I just edited my question. We can also restrict $x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. As explained in the question it is is sufficient to show that
$$h(y)=e^{2y} (\alpha^2y^2 - 2 \alpha y + 2) - e^y (\alpha y^2 - 2\alpha y + 4) + 2 \geq 0.$$
Using the Taylor series expansion $e^y=\sum_{r=0}^{+\infty}\frac{y^r}{r!}$, which converges for all $y$, we find
$$
  h(y)=\sum_{r=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(2y)^r}{r!} (\alpha^2y^2 - 2 \alpha y + 2) - \sum_{r=0}^{+\infty}\frac{y^r}{r!} (\alpha y^2 - 2\alpha y + 4) + 2\\
= \sum_{r=2}^{+\infty}y^{r}\left(\alpha\frac{\alpha 2^{r-2} -1}{(r-2)!} + \alpha \frac{2-2^{r}}{(r-1)!} + \frac{2^{r+1}-4}{r!} \right)
$$
where the second equality comes from the grouping of all terms of the same order. To show that $h(y)\geq 0$ for $y>0$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$, it is thus sufficient to show that for all $r\geq 2$
$$ \alpha\frac{2^{r-2}\alpha  - 1}{(r-2)!}+\alpha\frac{2-2^{r}}{(r-1)!}+\frac{2^{r+1}-4}{r!} \geq 0\\
  \leftrightarrow \alpha^2 2^{r-2}r(r-1)+\alpha r(3-2^{r}-r)+2^{r+1}-4 \geq 0.$$
For $r=2$, this is verified as $2\alpha^2 -6\alpha +4 = 2(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)$ is always positive for $\alpha \in [0,1]$.

For $r=3$, this is also verified as $\alpha^2 12 -\alpha 24 + 12  = 12 (\alpha-1)^2$ is again positive for $\alpha \in [0,1]$.

For $r\geq 4$, we have $r(r-1)\geq r^2/2$, $3-2^{r}-r\geq -2^{r+1}$ and $-2^{-r+4}\geq -1$ so that
$$ \alpha^2 2^{r-2}r(r-1)+\alpha r(3-2^{r}-r)+2^{r+1}-4 
  \geq 2^{r-2}( \alpha^2  r^2/2 -\alpha r 8+8-2^{-r+4})\\
  \geq 2^{r-2}( \alpha^2  r^2/2 -\alpha r 8+7)
$$
which roots are in $8r\pm \sqrt{50} r$. Given that $8r - \sqrt{50} r \geq 0.92 r > 1 $ for $r\geq 2$, both roots are strictly larger than 1 and the term is positive for $\alpha \in [0,1]$, which concludes the proof.