# Is $f(x)=\frac{\left(\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\gamma_k (e^{\zeta_kx}-1)\right)^{\alpha}}{x}$ convex? (with $0\leq\alpha\leq 1$, $x>0,\gamma_k>0,\zeta_k>0$)

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Is $f(x)=\frac{\left(\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\gamma_k (e^{\zeta_kx}-1)\right)^{\alpha}}{x}$ convex? (with $0\leq\alpha\leq 1$, $x>0,\gamma_k>0,\zeta_k>0$)

I am trying to show that the above function is convex with $0\leq\alpha\leq 1$, $x>0,\gamma_k>0,\zeta_k>0$ for $k=0,...,K-1$. This is a generalization of the question asked in
[Is $(e^x-1)^\alpha/x$ convex? (with $0\leq\alpha\leq 1$ and $x>0$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4688760/963945).

I tried to follow the same methodology in the solution and in particular the convexity composition rule. Indeed, given that $f(x)=e^{g(x)}$, we have
\begin{align*}
 f''(x)&=e^{g(x)}(g'(x))^2+e^{g(x)}g''(x)
\end{align*}
and it is sufficient to show that $g(x)$ is convex, i.e., $g''(x) \geq 0$. The derivatives are given by (easier to write in vector form)
$$
 g(x)=\log f(x)\\
 =\alpha\log (\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\gamma_k (e^{\zeta_kx}-1)) -\log x\\
 =\alpha\log (\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\gamma}}^T (e^{x\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\zeta}}}-\boldsymbol{\mathrm{1}})) -\log x
$$
$$g'(x)= \alpha \frac{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\gamma}}^T\boldsymbol{\mathrm{D}_\zeta}e^{x\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\zeta}}}}{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\gamma}}^T (e^{x\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\zeta}}}-\boldsymbol{\mathrm{1}})} - \frac{1}{x}$$

$$g''(x)= \alpha \frac{\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\gamma}}^T\boldsymbol{\mathrm{D}}_\zeta^2 e^{x\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\zeta}}}\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\gamma}}^T (e^{x\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\zeta}}}-\boldsymbol{\mathrm{1}})-(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\gamma}}^T \boldsymbol{\mathrm{D}} e^{x\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\zeta}}})^2}{(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\gamma}}^T (e^{x\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\zeta}}}-\boldsymbol{\mathrm{1}}))^2} + \frac{1}{x^2}.
$$
and we need to show that this term is positive. The $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\gamma}}$ dependence can be put out by putting on left and right but I get stuck... I can provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generalization is interesting.

More generally consider a positive measure $\gamma(d\xi)$ on the positive line such that $$L(s)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{s\xi}\xi \gamma(d\xi)<\infty$$ for all $s>0.$ Then $L_1(x)=\int_0^1L(xu)du$ is also a Laplace transform (actually of the multiplicative convolution of the Lebesgue measure restricted to $[0,1]$ with the measure $\xi \gamma(d\xi)$.) Therefore $k_1=\log L_1$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$ (by Holder). To see that $$f(x)= (L_1(x))^{\alpha}\times \frac{1}{x^{1-\alpha}}$$ is convex, enough is to see that
$$(\log f)''(x)=\alpha k_1''(x)+\frac{1-\alpha}{x^2}\geq 0.$$ Application: $$\gamma(d\xi)=\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}\gamma_i\delta_{\xi_i}(d\xi).$$

Comment: Not very familiar with measure theory but I guess this is a further generalization. Do you think it may help to solve the question?

Comment: Hello. Which question? If the question is : show that your function is convex, the post gives a complete proof.

Comment: I don't get it, how is your function $L_1(x)$ related to the original function $f(x)$?

Comment: OK, let us do the calculation together. $$L(s)=\sum_{i}e^{s\xi_i}\xi_i \gamma_i$$$$L_1(x)=\int_0^1L(xu)du=\sum_i\frac{e^{x\xi_i}-1}{x}\gamma_i=\frac{A}{x}$$$$f(x)=\frac{A^{\alpha}}{x}=\left(\frac{A}{x}\right)^{\alpha}\times \frac{1}{x^{1-\alpha}}.$$

Comment: OK I see now, thanks! And about the last of the proof. Why is $k_1$ convex? What do you mean by Holder?

Comment: $k=\log L$ where $L$ is the Laplace transform of a positive measure $ \mu$ is convex. Indeed Holder says $$\int f(t)g (t)d\mu(t)\leq (\int  f^pd\mu)^{1/p} (\int  f^qd\mu)^{1/q}=(\int  f^{1/\lambda}d\mu)^{\lambda} (\int  f^{1/{1-\lambda}}d\mu)^{1-\lambda}$$ where $\lambda =1/p$ and $1-\lambda =1/q.$ Now choose $f(t)=e^{\lambda xt}$ and $g(t)=e^{(1-\lambda)y t}.$ You get $$L(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq L(x)^{\lambda}L(y)^{1-\lambda}$$ Taking the log it says that $k$ is convex. Note that $k$ convex implies $L$ convex.

Comment: Great thank you! Nice solution in the end, to the point, even if the problem seemed more complicated!

Comment: FYI I could also arrive to the result ($k_1''\geq 0$) using a similar argument as you used in the particular case $K=1$ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4688760/963945. Basically, the sinh bound but it is longer than your proof here. I can also provide it if useful.

Comment: Sure, we are always curious of new ideas. Provide, please.

Comment: Provided! As mentioned, not as lean as yours ;)

Answer (score 1):

Following the notations in the question, we can rewrite $g''(x)$ as
$$ g''(x)= \alpha \frac{\boldsymbol{\gamma}^T\boldsymbol{D}_\zeta^2 e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}}\boldsymbol{\gamma}^T (e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}}-\boldsymbol{1})-(\boldsymbol{\gamma}^T\boldsymbol{D}_\zeta e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}})^2+  \frac{1}{x^2}(\boldsymbol{\gamma}^T (e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}}-\boldsymbol{1}))^2}{(\boldsymbol{\gamma}^T (e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}}-\boldsymbol{1}))^2} +(1-\alpha) \frac{1}{x^2}$$
which second term is positive and first term is positive if (removing dependence in $\alpha$ and expanding)
$$ \frac{\boldsymbol{\gamma}^T\left(\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{D}_\zeta^2 e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}} (e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}}-\boldsymbol{1})^T+\frac{1}{2}(e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}}-\boldsymbol{1})e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}^T}\boldsymbol{D}_\zeta^2- \boldsymbol{D}_\zeta e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}} e^{x \boldsymbol{\zeta}^T}  \boldsymbol{D}_\zeta+\frac{1}{x^2}(e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}}-\boldsymbol{1})(e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}}-\boldsymbol{1})^T\right)\boldsymbol{\gamma}}{\boldsymbol{\gamma}^T (e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}}-\boldsymbol{1})(e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}}-\boldsymbol{1})^T\boldsymbol{\gamma}}
$$
and is positive if
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{D}_\zeta^2 e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}} (e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}}-\boldsymbol{1})^T+\frac{1}{2}(e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}}-\boldsymbol{1})e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}^T}\boldsymbol{D}_\zeta^2- \boldsymbol{D}_\zeta e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}} e^{x \boldsymbol{\zeta}^T}  \boldsymbol{D}_\zeta+\frac{1}{x^2}(e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}}-\boldsymbol{1})(e^{x\boldsymbol{\zeta}}-\boldsymbol{1})^T
\end{align*}
is positive semidefinite. A sufficient condition is that all elements are positive. They are given by
$$\frac{1}{2}\zeta_k^2 e^{x\zeta_k} (e^{x\zeta_{k'}}-1)+\frac{1}{2}(e^{x\zeta_k}-1)e^{x\zeta_{k'}}\zeta_{k'}^2- \zeta_k e^{x\zeta_k} e^{x \zeta_{k'}}  \zeta_{k'}+\frac{(e^{x\zeta_{k}}-1)(e^{x\zeta_{k'}}-1)}{x^2}$$
$$ =\frac{1}{2}\zeta_k^2 e^{x\zeta_k} (e^{x\zeta_{k'}}-1)+\frac{1}{2}(e^{x\zeta_k}-1)e^{x\zeta_{k'}}\zeta_{k'}^2- \zeta_k e^{x\zeta_k} e^{x \zeta_{k'}}  \zeta_{k'}+\frac{4e^{\frac{x(\zeta_{k}+\zeta_{k'})}{2}}\sinh(\frac{x\zeta_{k}}{2})\sinh(\frac{x\zeta_{k'}}{2})}{x^2}
$$
This term can be lower bounded using $\sinh(x)\geq x$ for $x\geq 0$. Hence, it is sufficient to show that the following term is positive
$$
 \frac{1}{2}\zeta_k^2 e^{x\zeta_k} (e^{x\zeta_{k'}}-1)+\frac{1}{2}(e^{x\zeta_k}-1)e^{x\zeta_{k'}}\zeta_{k'}^2- \zeta_k e^{x\zeta_k} e^{x \zeta_{k'}}  \zeta_{k'}+\zeta_ke^{x\zeta_k/2}e^{x\zeta_{k'}/2}\zeta_{k'}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\zeta_ke^{x\zeta_k/2}-e^{x\zeta_{k'}/2}\zeta_{k'}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}\zeta_k^2 e^{x\zeta_k} e^{x\zeta_{k'}}+\frac{1}{2}e^{x\zeta_k}e^{x\zeta_{k'}}\zeta_{k'}^2- \zeta_k e^{x\zeta_k} e^{x \zeta_{k'}}  \zeta_{k'}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\zeta_ke^{x\zeta_k/2}-e^{x\zeta_{k'}/2}\zeta_{k'}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}e^{x\zeta_k} e^{x\zeta_{k'}}\left(\zeta_k-\zeta_{k'}\right)^2
$$
This happens when
$$
e^{x\zeta_k} e^{x\zeta_{k'}}\left(x\zeta_k-x\zeta_{k'}\right)^2\geq \left(x\zeta_ke^{x\zeta_k/2}-xe^{x\zeta_{k'}/2}\zeta_{k'}\right)^2
$$
$$
e^{a+b}(a-b)^2\geq (ae^{a/2}-be^{b/2})^2
$$
where $a=x\zeta_{k}$ and $b=x\zeta_{k'}$. Let us consider that $a \geq b$ (otherwise symmetric), we should then show that
$$
 e^{\frac{a+b}{2}}(a-b)\geq ae^{a/2}-be^{b/2}$$
$$e^{y+x}(y-x)\geq ye^{y}-xe^{x}$$
where we defined $y=a/2$ and $x=b/2$. We can follow the proof in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4769586/963945. Subtracting $(y-x)e^y$ gives
$$
 x(e^{y}-e^x)\leq (e^{y+x}-e^y)(y-x)
$$
Dividing by $e^y$
$$
 x(1-e^{x-y})\leq (e^{x}-1)(y-x).
$$
We can now use the product of the two following inequalities to arrive to the result
$$
 x \leq e^x-1$$
$$ 1-e^{x-y}\leq y-x.
$$

Comment: This  is a tour de force...