# Consider that $a>0$ and $b>0$, can we show that $e^{a+b}(a-b)^2\geq (ae^{a/2}-be^{b/2})^2$?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider that $a>0$ and $b>0$, can we show that
$e^{a+b}(a-b)^2\geq (ae^{a/2}-be^{b/2})^2$? I believe it to be the case, through simulations and intuitively but I cannot show it even though I guess there is a simple proof.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Expand and observe similarites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming WLOG that $a<b$ and taking the square root of your inequality and replacing $a,b$ by $2y,2x$ your inequality is equivalent to
$$ y e^{y}-x e^{x} \leq e^{y+x}(y-x), \quad 0<x<y.$$
Subtracting $(y-x)e^y$ from both sides and simplifying we get that this is equivalent to showing
$$ x (e^{y}- e^{x}) \leq ( e^{y+x} - e^y)(y-x), \quad 0<x<y.$$
Now the latter follows from the basic inequalities
$$ x \leq e^x-1$$
and
$$ 1- e^{x-y} \leq y-x .$$
(Just take the product of those two inequalities and then multiply by $e^y$.)

Comment: Nice, thank you! simple and to the point!

Comment: You’re welcome. …I used a geometric picture involving rectangles related to the graph of the exponential to come up with the equivalent inequality, but it would have been less to-the-point to include it :-)

Comment: Curious to know about your geometric picture, always interested to know more about it!

Comment: Btw, I reused your proof in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4767145/is-fx-frac-left-sum-k-0k-1-gamma-k-e-zeta-kx-1-right-alpha/4770986#4770986 :)

Comment: Oh cool :-)  ...I was wondering if this was part of a bigger puzzle.